# Java daysPassed method

Tags: java

I have this method in this java program that I am working on for school. The method works fine, but I was wondering if there is way to make it shorter. Any advice would be great.

```
public int calculateDate(int month, int day, int year, int numOfDays)
{

    if((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 0 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) < 32)
    {
        dMonth = 1;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays;
    } // end of if

    if(((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 31 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays < 61)) && isLeapYear(year) == true)
    {
        dMonth = 2;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - 31;
    }// end of if

    if((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 31 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) < 60)
    {
        dMonth = 2;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - 31;
    }// end of if

    if(((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 60 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays < 92)) && isLeapYear(year) == true){
        dMonth = 3;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - 31 - 29;
    }// end of if

    if((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 59 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) < 91)
    {
        dMonth = 3;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - 31 - 28;
    }// end of if

    if(((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 91 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays < 122)) && isLeapYear(year) == true)
    {
        dMonth = 4;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (2 * 31) - 29;
    }// end of if

    if((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 90 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) < 121)
    {
        dMonth = 4;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (2 * 31) - 28;
    }// end of if

    if(((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 121 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays < 153)) && isLeapYear(year) == true){
        dMonth = 5;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (2 * 31) - 29 - 30;
    }// end of if

    if((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 120 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) < 152)
    {
        dMonth = 5;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (2 * 31) - 28 - 30;
    }// end of if

    if(((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 152 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays < 183)) && isLeapYear(year) == true){
        dMonth = 6;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (3 * 31) - 29 - 30;
    }// end of if

    if((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 151 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) < 182)
    {
        dMonth = 6;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (3 * 31) - 28 - 30;
    }// end of if

    if(((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 182 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays < 214)) && isLeapYear(year) == true)
    {
        dMonth = 7;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (3 * 31) - 29 - (2 * 30);
    }// end of if

    if((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 181 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) < 213)
    {
        dMonth = 7;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (3 * 31) - 28 - (2 * 30);
    }// end of if

    if(((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 213 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays < 245)) && isLeapYear(year) == true)
    {
        dMonth = 8;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (4 * 31) - 29 - (2 * 30);
    }// end of if

    if((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 212 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) < 244)
    {
        dMonth = 8;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (4 * 31) - 28 - (2 * 30);
    }// end of if

    if(((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 244 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays < 275)) && isLeapYear(year) == true)
    {
        dMonth = 9;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (5 * 31) - 29 - (2 * 30);
    }// end of if

    if((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 243 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) < 274)
    {
        dMonth = 9;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (5 * 31) - 28 - (2 * 30);
    }// end of if

    if(((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 274 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays < 306)) && isLeapYear(year) == true)
    {
        dMonth = 10;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (5 * 31) - 29 - (3 * 30);
    }// end of if

    if((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 273 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) < 305)
    {
        dMonth = 10;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (5 * 31) - 28 - (3 * 30);
    }// end of if

    if(((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 305 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays < 336)) && isLeapYear(year) == true)
    {
        dMonth = 11;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (6 * 31) - 29 - (3 * 30);
    }// end of if

    if((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 304 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) < 335)
    {
        dMonth = 11;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (6 * 31) - 28 - (3 * 30);
    }// end of if

    if(((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 335 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays < 367)) && isLeapYear(year) == true)
    {
        dMonth = 12;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (6 * 31) - 29 - (4 * 30);
    }// end of if

    if((daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) > 334 && (daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays) < 366)
    {
        dMonth = 12;
        dDay = daysPassed(month,day,year) + numOfDays - (6 * 31) - 28 - (4 * 30);
    }// end of if

    return dDay;
}// end of calulateDateenter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Java 8+, you might use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) like

```
public int calculateDate(int month, int day, int year, int numOfDays) {
    return LocalDate.of(year, month, day).plusDays(numOfDays).getDayOfMonth();
}
```

If you actually need to set `dMonth` (and `dDay`) too, you could do that as well

```
public int calculateDate(int month, int day, int year, int numOfDays) {
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(year, month, day).plusDays(numOfDays);
    dMonth = ld.getMonthValue();
    dDay = ld.getDayOfMonth();
    return dDay;
}
```

Comment: how would you call this from another class?

Comment: How do you call your current method? Same way.

Comment: if I type in 3/18/2015 for my date, them I add 25(numOfDays) to it the new date is 4/18/2015, but should be 4/12/2015. How I fix that? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: I get 12 with this

Comment: System.out.println(date.calculateDate(month, day, year, numDays));

Comment: but if I use this I get 18
  System.out.print("The new date is: " + date);

Comment: @MichaelJames See edit. If you want to set the Month and Day fields (and Year), you need to do that. Also, you might want to set a year (because that might also change)... unfortunately, I'm guessing because you didn't post all of your code.

Comment: all I had to do was make dDay = ld.getDayOfMonth();

Comment: You probably also want to add a `dYear = ld.getYear();` (assuming the year is `dYear`).

Comment: could you use this same idea and calculate the days passed from the beginning of the year?

Comment: ?@ElliottFrisch

Comment: `public int calculateDate(int year, int numOfDays) { return this.calculateDate(1,1,year,numOfDays); }`

Comment: this is only giving days since the beginning of the month not beginning of the year @ElliottFrisch